# Formula in latex displays differently

Tags: align, overleaf, math-operators

I would like to write this formula in overleaf latex as shown below
[image]

With the equation I wrote in latex, it looks like below where you can see all the equations after star displays differently. Could someone please help?.

What is tried:

```
\begin{align*}
A_0^\ (m) &= g_m \sum_k W_o_k^\ (m) \star \ A_k^\
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: Overleaf indicates errors with your attempt (the red number).  Once TeX hits an error, the output pdf is TeX's best guess, and shouldn't be relied upon.  Generally speaking, `_` or `^` will only affect the next single character. If you want more than one, you need to enclose the subscript or superscript in `{}` (and there's no harm in enclosing a single character).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
  \documentclass{article}
    
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{bm}
    \begin{document} 
    
    \begin{align*}
    % A_0^\ (m) = g_m \sum_k W_o_k^\ (m) \star \ A_k^\
    \bm{A}_{0}^{(m)} = g_{m}\left(\sum_{k}\;\bm{W}_{ok}^{(m)} \;\ast\; \bm{A}_{k}^{(m-1)} + b_{o}^{(m)}\right)
    \end{align*}
    
    
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is it something like this you want?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\[
 \bm{A}_o^{(m)}= g_m \Bigl(\sum\nolimits_k \bm{W}_{ok}^{(m)}\bm{\ast }\bm{A}_k^{m-1} + b_{o}^{(m)}\Bigr),
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]